# Convert JQUERY function into native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been attempting to convert a JQUERY function into JavaScript. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The values returned when I rewrote the function in JS all return 0.0.

Here is the JQUERY code I am wanting to convert to pure JavaScript:

```
$('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')').each(function () {
    getAverage('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')', 'subTotal');
})
```

Basically I want to remove the .each() and use native JavaScript instead...

Here is the full code:

```
var el1 = $('#tableID > thead > tr > th:gt(17):not(.totalRow)');
var x = el1.length;
var starter = 19;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    $('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')').each(function () {
        getAverage('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')', 'subTotal');
    })
    starter += 1;
}
```

Here is the getAverage function to help understand what is happening:

```
//average function
function getAverage(a, b) {
    var $this, $content, tdTxt, theAvg; 
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    $(a).each(function () {
        $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
        $content = $this.html();
        tdTxt = parseFloat($this.text(), 10) || 0;
        if ($this.hasClass(b)) {
            theAvg = parseFloat((sum / count), 10) || 0;
            $this.text((theAvg).toFixed(2));
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
        } else {
            sum += parseFloat(tdTxt);
            if ($content == '') {
            }
            else {
                ++count; // this micro-optimization makes it marginally faster
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can't use the $.('tag') finder in Javascript.. That's a JQuery function

Comment: *Why* do you want to not use jquery? Especially since `$()` is the jquery constructor?

Comment: You want to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) insted of `$(selector)`.

Comment: @Cakes You probably mean [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: the jQuery code looks all kinds of wrong too

Comment: I want to convert this piece of code particularly from jquery to pure js because it is slower: $('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')').each(function () {
    getAverage('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')', 'subTotal');
})

Comment: @sm1l3y That's your logic which looks like slowing down it, not really the use of jQuery. Would be easier to help if you provide a jsFiddle

Comment: Not to mention the CSS selector. Stick a class on the elements you want and use that.

Comment: yes, @sm1l3y, you made the point in the question - that code looks like it will calculate the average for each "starter" multiple times

Comment: JSFIDDLE > https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/2azzqeh9/18/

Comment: Actually there are 32 columns, perhaps you did not scroll to the right? That current code in JQUERY returns perfectly I have just narrowed down that .each() as causing a performance hit...

Comment: sorry about that, I did scroll, but my eyes are bent and my back is blind :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ESNext code

```
Array.from(
  document
    .querySelectorAll('#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')')
  ).forEach(_=> getAverage(
    '#tableID > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + starter + ')',
    'subTotal'
  ))
```

Comment: Might want to mention that `Array.from` is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: `[].forEach.call(selector stuff, function)` - is more widely supported - although the polyfill for Array.from is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) ... and on yet another hand, the code in this answer is ES6 anyway ... so ...

Comment: Is there any serious programmer who doesn't transpile JavaScript from current ECMAScript spec?

Comment: Which serious programmer would still use `.forEach` when there are `for of` loops?

Comment: @JaromandaX …in environments that support it, of course, like the transpiler that marzelin wants to use.

Comment: @Bergi "Still use"? `forEach` is a method on new ES6 constructs (e.g., `Map` or `Set`) and I'd consider it more functionally-oriented than `for` loops, and you can pass functions to it, unlike `for` loops. I much prefer that style over old-school imperative-looking code.

Comment: @DaveNewton `forEach` does nothing but execute side effects, no better than a `for of` loop. It's more object-oriented, yes, but certainly not more functional - for that you'd need to use `map` or `reduce` which actually *return* something.

Comment: @Bergi "No better" from a technical standpoint, but from a readability standpoint, I'd disagree. I stand by my assertion that it's "more functionally-oriented", which explicitly does *not* state "this is functional".

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, and from a readability standpoint the extra function expression is even worse than `for of` loop.

Comment: actually @marzelin my bad your method works perfectly! much thanks!

Comment: @Bergi That's an opinion that I don't share, at all.

Comment: @Bergi (As a mostly-useless anecdote, several styleguides also recommend against iterators, e.g., https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#user-content-iterators--nope prefers `forEach` over `for-in/-of`.) This also meshes with my general tendency to put the functionality into an easily-testable method which can then be passed to `forEach`. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton the reasoning of that rule also recommends not to use `forEach`. So *when* you (have to) use mutability and side effects nonetheless, you can also use a `for of` loop - and probably should do so explicitly.

Comment: @Bergi We'll have to agree to disagree on that one--they advocate doing things the functional way ("best") but prefer the side-effects to live in a function rather than in a `for-x` ("good"). So do I, but I wouldn't fail a code review for it (probably :)